# javaScript onClick doesn't work when executed from page loaded inside a DIV on another page

Tags: javascript

I have two pages: home.php and metrics.php

If I load metrics.php directly, and click on the button associated with this code:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm dropdown-toggle" onClick ="$('#box-table-a').tableExport({type:'excel',escape:'false'});"> <img src='img/xls.png' width='24px'>Export Table Data</button>
```

**it executes this tableExport javascript file correctly and exports a file for me.**

However, I'm not loading metrics.php directly into the address bar.  I am using a dropdown on main.php:

```
<select class="navbar-inverse" placeholder="Report" onchange="showPage(this.value)">
  <option value="/main.php">Report</option>
  <option value="/metrics.php">Metrics</option>
</select>
```

which then populates metrics.php into a DIV on this main.php page through this javaScript function:

```
function showPage(str) {
  if (str !==".PM") {
    if (str=="") {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
      return;
    } 
  }
  $("#txtHint").load((str));
}
</script>
```

### Question:

What specifically is causing this button to work properly when I have metrics.php loaded directly, but not when it's loaded inside a DIV on main.php?

I don't get any errors in my console, I just click the button and nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried replacing your onclick with an alert() to see whether it has anything to do with the way its loaded? (ie, does javascript simply not work like that?)

Comment: hmmm... so `onClick = alert("yo")` works just fine.  So... there is something that is allowing THAT to function, but not `"$('#box-table-a').tableExport({type:'excel',escape:'false'});"> <img src='img/xls.png' width='24px'` I don't know what that thing is though...

Comment: Have you tried adding 'return false;' after your onclick function (aka `onclick="myfunction(); return false"`) to prevent any other thing from executing? And does `#box-table-a` exist?

Comment: I haven't tried `return: false`, but the code executes FINE when I load metrics.php into the address bar - just not when it's loaded inside a DIV on main.php.  #box-table-a does exist.  I am getting an `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error now when I click the button.

Comment: I have `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` loaded both on my main.php and my metrics.php pages...

Comment: This means that either jQuery isn't loaded (and `$` is not a function) or `tableExport` isn't loaded. Try using @user1489187 's answer bel;ow to actually tie it after load (just add it after your load() function to tie any newly loaded code to any new events). He might actually have been right.

Comment: If I have the jquery.js and the tableExport.js files loaded in the <head> section of my metrics.php page, why would they NOT load when I load metrics.php inside of the main.php DIV.  I think that is my MAIN question - why it works when I load metrics.php directly, but not when I load it inside the DIV.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the event onclick is bound before the subpage loads via ajax, so new HTML nodes are not bound when they are created.
You can use jquery´[s live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function to bind onclick. Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#your_node").live("click","your function here");
```

});

Comment: This is not the case as onclick does not care about 'loaded'. If you wait five seconds until the entire DOM is loaded then the onclick fires exactly as it should. It would be true if it was bound outside the DOM.

Comment: so @somethinghere , what do you think is causing this?  I'm sure it's something simple that I just don't understand yet (I'm still somewhat new,) but I can't figure it out...

Comment: I'm not sure about what is causing is. What is your console saying after you clicked it? Are there any errors? Otherwise try to move everything in your `onclick` into a function called `wrapperFunction()` inside a seperate JS file, load that in and then call `onclick="wrapperFunction(); return false;"`. I can't guarantee it will work, thats why I'm not posting an answer.

Comment: I don't get what the `return false` does, and what its purpose is here - especially when this works outside of the page-->#DIV setup I've got going on now.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have the tableExport plugin loaded on home.php. `<script>`s inside dynamically loaded HTML are NOT run. If you want jQuery and the tableExport plugin to work on home.php, you have to include them there, or else parse the contents of metrics.php and manually `eval()` all the JavaScript.

***Update***
Just thought of this solution:

```
$("#txtHint").load(str, function () {
    // check whether tableExport plugin is loaded
    if (typeof $.tableExport !== "function") {
        $.getScript("/path-to/tableExport.js");
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, `#box-table-a` is on metrics.php.  Even if I make this change, I still get the same error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function `

Comment: That's interesting - because I have the scripts loaded BOTH in my main.php AND my metrics.php pages.  Let me try this solution, (I have to figure out where it goes first, so give me a minute.)  I'll report back.

Comment: It goes in your `showPage` function, replacing the current `.load((str))`.

Comment: Is the path to tableExport.js correct in home.php? You're sure it's loading?